# SQL search query using LIKE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

**Problem:**

I am trying to use a full text index in my SQL search query but for some reason it does not return any posts from the database.

**PHP/SQL code:**

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchtext']);

$query = "SELECT
            EID,
            CONCAT (u1.Firstname, ' ', u1.Lastname) AS Examiner,
            Supervisor,
            ExaminationDate,
            FirstAuthor,
            SecondAuthor,
            Level,
            Credits,
            Completed
        FROM betyg_essays grade
            INNER JOIN betyg_users u1 ON grade.Examiner = u1.UID
        WHERE
            MATCH (Supervisor, FirstAuthor, SecondAuthor) AGAINST ('$string')
        ORDER BY
            EID ASC
";
```

**MySQL Table definition:**

[image]

**Column in database with two posts:**

[image]

**Scenario:**

If I only search for "per" it should return the second post.

Comment: Can you provide the table DDL? How did you specify the fulltext index?

Comment: Surround the search term in percentage signs?

Comment: You are very vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) right now! Escape your input, and/or start using PDO or Mysqli!

Comment: @AndreBacklund I have done that, no change. To Bono: I applied mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: ... and your table definition is?

Comment: @acme http://screencast.com/t/pClDIP4m9m

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer - did you check you are using a MySQL version supporting InnoDB fulltext indices? And are you really sure you defined a fulltext index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fulltext index definition is correct (you should post your table definition), MySQL does only index at least 4-letter-words on a standard installation. You have to change that in the `my.cnf` by setting [`ft_min_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) if you want to support 3-letter-words in your search:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Besides, you should check the threshold and stopword list as described in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

**edit:**

According to your [table definition](http://content.screencast.com/users/elements/folders/Jing/media/4246b303-9d64-4c1f-b74b-55b91062bfc5/00001344.png) you are using an InnoDB table which does not support fulltext indexes until MySQL 5.6.4. Is that fullfilled? And I can't see any fulltext index defined in your definition.

There should be something like this:

```
... FULLTEXT KEY `keywords` (`keywords`) ...
```

To add a fulltext index to your table use the `ALTER TABLE` syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE betyg_essays ADD FULLTEXT(FIELD1, FIELD2, ...);
```

Comment: I tried searching for "svensson" but it gave me zero results.

Comment: Would you recommend MyISAM instead? I'm not sure if I have defined a fulltext index, any chance I could get any advice on this issue?

Comment: If your server installation is below MySQL 5.6.4 you must use MyISAM for a fulltext index, there is no option (or use a server search engine like Sphinx). I'd suggest you take a look at http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/ which describes the use of fulltext indexes quite well.

Comment: I updated my post with current code and table definition but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the link.